# Python: determine number of elements in a list passed as a function argument

Tags: python, testing

I have some function `foo(list)`

and i want to

```
assert foo(list with one element) == that one element

assert foo(list with 100 elements) == foo(list)
```

how do I do this without knowing what the list itself is and ideally with just assert statements?

Comment: Like @VaughnCato asks, if you are using the `unittest` module, the assert methods there will be smart enough to do the right thing. In Python >= 2.7, `unittest.assertEqual` uses a more specialised method for different types.

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(x) == 1:
    assert foo(x) == x[0]
elif len(x) == 100:
    assert foo(x) == x
```

Or, if you wish to be certain that `foo`'s return value always has the above properties, you could do this:

```
def foo(x):
    # compute return value `retval` based on `x`
    if len(x) == 1:
        assert retval == x[0]
    elif len(x) == 100:
        assert retval == x
    return retval
```

Comment: Thanks! I can do this without defining x ahead of time?

Comment: Or, you could put it at the end of the definition of `foo`... (I'll edit the post to show what I mean.)